# Generate list of types from C++ header file

Tags: c++, reflection

I have implemented a reflection engine in C++, and I can construct types and add them to the reflection database like so:

```
TypeInfo* spark_math_Vector2_type = new TypeInfo();
spark_math_Vector2_type->setName("Vector2");
spark_math_Vector2_type->setFullName("::spark::math::Vector2");
spark_math_Vector2_type->setHash(typeid(spark::math::Vector2).hash_code());
spark_math_Vector2_type->setSize(sizeof(spark::math::Vector2));
Reflection::getInstance().registerType(spark_math_Vector2_type);
```

However, I now want to automate the generation of the type database. To do this I need a way of getting all of the types created within C++ headers, and the constructors / methods / fields of the types.

I have found [gccxml](http://gccxml.github.io/HTML/Index.html), however it has various drawbacks (being too slow etc). Is there any other exiting tool / framework available? Or maybe there is a better way of doing this? (I really do not want to have to write a parser...)

Comment: Too slow...?  How so?  Yes, you are right, you do not want to write a parser for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your choices are:

- Edison Design Group front end
- GCC  (GCCXML is derived from this)
- Clang
- (Our) DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit with its C++14 front-end

EDG is commercial, but I think free for research purposes.  GCC wants to be a compiler, and will tend to fight you trying to bend it to other purposes.  Clang seems well designed for tasks like this.    We think DMS (also commercial) is well designed for this.